# git command to get commit details for a specific file

Tags: git, github

I wanted to see list of commits and user who committed it for a file using git command.

Say i have a file in git path `/home/git/xml/a.xml` in `master` branch

Now, i wanted get list of `commits and user who did the commit` etc on above file.

Please let me know the command to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git log` with the filename here:

```
git log xml/a.xml
```

assuming your project is in `/home/git`.

You can try something on the line of `git log -n5 <filename>`, to limit the numbers of commits shown.

Comment: Thanks. Its giving huge history. how to control. say display only last 5 changes

Comment: @logan You can try something on the line of `git log -n5 <filename>`, to limit the numbers of commits shown.

If that helped, don't forget to accept and upvote :)